# Logrotate not rotating on file size

Tags: linux, cron, logrotate

According to the man page "Normally, logrotate is run as a daily cron job.  It will not  modify  a log  multiple  times  in  one  day unless the criterium for that log is based on the log’s size". So, this means that even though cron runs hourly/daily/weekly, if I set a size parameter, cron settings will be ignored and the file will be rotated as soon as its size reaches, e.g., 10k.

I have the following in my `logrotate.conf` but the maillog is not rotated, i.e., the `touch /var/log/maillog` is not executed:

```
/var/log/maillog
{
    missingok
    notifempty
    nocompress
    size=10k
    postrotate
        touch /var/log/maillog
    endscript
}
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your syntax - size=10k should be size 10k as follows:

`/var/log/maillog
{
    missingok
    notifempty
    nocompress
    size 10k
    postrotate
        touch /var/log/maillog
    endscript
}`